# Linq recursive query get all siblings

Tags: c#, linq

The objective is to make a Linq query to the database that gets the rest of ids that link back the input id in the method called GetFolder

```
Sample Data
Id              parentId
10              9
11              10
12              10
13              12
14              13
15              13
100             20

Expected Output
Id              parentId
10              11
12              10
13              12
14              13

  public class Folder 
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Parent_Id")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Folder> Children { get; set; }
  }
```

Have the ICollection allows me to go one view the siblings of that folder.
GetFolders methods return these:

```
Id              parentId
10              11
11              10
12              10

    private async Task<Folder> GetFolder(int folderId)
    {
      var entity = await Database.Folders
        .Where(e => e.Id == folderId)
        .Include(e => e.Children)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

      return entity;
    }
```

I tried to write a recursive function to get the rest of the Ids but it doesn't work correctly. 
Does anyone have any recommends on how to write this recursive function to receive the rest of the Ids.

Comment: In your example, 10 and 11 are eachother's parents - is that intentional? If so you'll have to ensure the recursion doesn't end up in a loop.

Comment: a recursive function is a function which  calls itself.  This function suppose to have `int folderId` as input parameter. With each call you need to do something with input parameter , for example do increasing  ... but you can't increase value infinitely, you have to set a  limit

Comment: that was a mistake. what i tried to do was add all the values returned for the linq into a hash list  and then do a foreach (var id inListId.tolist){ GetFolder}  and it will keep all until all the values are obtained but it did not work and is very messy coding wise. i dont know the limit so thats the issue with this

Comment: do you know the max  of parentId at the moment  when you call GetFolder ?

Comment: i dont know the max limit so thats the issue with this. i get the folderid from clicking on the folder button on the front end. this is basically the same of the folder structure on windows but i dont know how deep the folder structure goes.

Comment: you need to go through subfolders or read data from database ?

Comment: Does the query have to be translatable to SQL? Or can you just fetch the entire folder structure into your memory and run a LINQ-to-objects query?

Comment: If I fetch the entire folder structure it could be massive so i would prefer to loop through the subfolders with a linq query, I am trying to write a query to go through each subfolder but the code i wrote doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Well, by "entire" I meant the substructure rooted at the root folder. I assume it's a tree. Sorry for not being precise.

Comment: @user10609979 if you need " a query to go through each subfolder"  could you edit you question ...  as understand , you want to click a folder and get a list of sub-folders, right ?

Comment: Yes it a tree structure but iam not going back to the root. I am going forward. if i was going back to the root i could write something this. all my root folders are null                                   while(folder.Parent.Id != null) 
        {
          var parent = await GetFolder(folder.Parent.Id.Value);
          folder.Parent = parent;
          folder = parent;
        }

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
IEnumerable<int> GetRelatedIds(Folder root)
{        
    var ids = root.Children.SelectMany(c => GetRelatedIds(c)).ToList();
    ids.Add(root.Id);

    return ids;
}
```

This will also include the Id of the root folder. If you don't need it you can either just remove it from the list (it will be the last element), or run this method for all children of the root and concatenate the results.

Comment: yes i was trying something very similar to that so i will try an improve it.